# What is the equivalent of deprecated ItemContextMenuDisplay in outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I would like to add a menu item to the context menu when the user right clicks on a message.

But the item

```
Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay
```

Is apparently deprecated, what would be the equivalent of this in outlook 2013?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    // new class override Office.IRibbonExtensibility
}
...
```

To create the Office.IRibbonExtensibility class simply select "Project > Add > New item > Ribbon (XML)

And edit the created XML accordingly.

The menu item has an 'onAction' callback that can handle when the user selects your menu item.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Command Bars were deprecated and now the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) is used for customizing context menus. See [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) to get started quickly.

The replacement of the Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay event is any callback defined in the XML markup of your ribbon controls for the context menu. They are invoked by the office to get the values.